# Can i get my facebook's email address when i log in facebook from facebook connect api?

Tags: email, facebook

Can i get my facebook's email address  when i log in facebook from facebook connect api?Thanks.

Comment: Please reformat your question and add more details. I cannot understand completely what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for the [email permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions), then you can get it using the [Graph API](https://graph.facebook.com/). For example: http://fbrell.com/fb.api/user-info:

```
<fb:login-button perms="email"></fb:login-button>
<div id="me"></div>

<script>
var
  div    = document.getElementById('me'),
  showMe = function(response) {
    if (!response.session) {
      div.innerHTML = '<em>Not Connected</em>';
    } else {
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        var html = '<table>';
        for (var key in response) {
          html += (
            '<tr>' +
              '<th>' + key + '</th>' +
              '<td>' + response[key] + '</td>' +
            '</tr>'
          );
        }
        div.innerHTML = html;
      });
    }
  };
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  showMe(response);
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', showMe);
});
</script>
```